# JsonSerializable - fromJson throwing _InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic> exception on nested object

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

I have used this `build.yaml` config to allow nested objects to be parsed to json:

```
targets:
    $default:
        builders:
            json_serializable:
                options:
                    explicit_to_json: true
```

It definitely seems to have worked as the `toJson` with nested objects works fine. Then I'm trying to create a class instance from json with https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable:

```
  @override
  UserRegistrationEntity getUserRegistration() {
    final json = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
        localDataSource.get(keyToRead: UserRegistrationFieldNames.self) ??
            <String, dynamic>{});
    return UserRegistrationEntity.fromJson(json); <===== ERROR ON THIS LINE
  }
```

I'm getting this exception:

> Thrown exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is
> not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

This is the value of `json`:

[image]

The red covered values are strings. When the `user_credential_entity.password` and `user_credential_entity.emailAddress` are `null`, there is no error.

I think it's because `user_credential_entity` is a nested JsonSerializable object. However `toJson` works, but `fromJson` doesn't.

the parent class:

```
part 'user_registration_entity.g.dart';



@JsonSerializable()
class UserRegistrationEntity implements IEntity<UserRegistrationEntity> {
  UserRegistrationEntity(
      {this.nickName,
      this.emailAddress,
      this.confirmEmailAddress,
      this.password,
      this.confirmPassword,
      this.userCredentialEntity});

  factory UserRegistrationEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserRegistrationEntityFromJson(json);

  String nickName;
  String emailAddress;
  String confirmEmailAddress;
  String password;
  String confirmPassword;
  UserCredentialEntity userCredentialEntity;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserRegistrationEntityToJson(this);
```

the child class:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class UserCredentialEntity implements IEntity<UserCredentialEntity> {
  UserCredentialEntity({this.password, this.emailAddress});

  factory UserCredentialEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserCredentialEntityFromJson(json);

  String password;
  String emailAddress;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserCredentialEntityToJson(this);
```

The actual line of code the error is on is here:

[image]

Is the value of `json['userCredentialEntity']` not a `Map<String, dynamic>`? Kinda looks like one to me.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to place this above the class which holds nested objects:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true, anyMap: true)
```

`anyMap: true` was the key for me.

Or instead, this can be added to `build.yaml`:

```
targets:
    $default:
        builders:
            json_serializable:
                options:
                    explicit_to_json: true
                    any_map: true
```

Which will mean `@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true, anyMap: true)` is no longer required.